# Не работают ::before и ::after

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть такой вот код:

```css
#search {
 background-color: #2c3e50;
 color: white;
 border-top: 1px solid #3a4e61;
}
#search_text {
 width: 164px;
 border-right: 1px solid #3a4e61;
 padding: 29px 0px 30px 87px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
#search_text::after {
 content: "";
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <div id="search_text">
    <p style="font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; color: #9fb0c0;">find your</p>
    <p style="font-size: 25px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">holydays</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

И этот последний `after` не работает до тех пор пока я что-то не напишу в `content` (пишу `content: "123"` и появляется) Что делать?

---

Надо было написать display: block;

Кто знает зачем это - объясните мне пожалуйста.

Comment: `display: block` пробовали?

Comment: Нет. Попробовал - появилось. А я так и не понял почему его не было? Не могли бы вы мне объяснить пожалуйста?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`display` - многоцелевое свойство, которое определяет, как элемент должен быть показан в документе. Коротко говоря, свойство `display` позволяет изменять тип элемента HTML.

`block` - элемент показывается как блочный. Применение этого значения для строчных элементов, например `<span>`, заставляет его вести подобно блокам - происходит перенос строк в начале и в конце содержимого.

*Синтаксис:*

```
display: block;
```

В вашем случае необходимо добавить это свойство для желаемого отображения:

```css
#search {
 background-color: #2c3e50;
 color: white;
 border-top: 1px solid #3a4e61;
}
#search_text {
 width: 164px;
 border-right: 1px solid #3a4e61;
 padding: 29px 0px 30px 87px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
#search_text::after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <div id="search_text">
    <p style="font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; color: #9fb0c0;">find your</p>
    <p style="font-size: 25px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">holydays</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Ссылки:*

[Свойство display (CSS) на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/display)
[Свойство display на Metanit](https://metanit.com/web/html5/8.5.php)

Comment: Спасибо большое